# How to return response from RabbitMQ to browser

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp, php-amqplib

I am trying to streamline my app to reduce server load by sending complex database tasks to a RabbitMQ queue for processing by a worker dyno.

For `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s, this has been relatively straightforward. However, I have a couple of intensive `SELECT`s which I would to send to the queue. The problem I'm having, however, is how to return the response to the user's browser when it's ready.

I understand I should be sending the response to a second queue, and creating a consumer in the client's browser. However, I'm hitting some practical problems in doing this, such as how to select the correct response from the queue, rather than simply the next response (e.g. if two people were on the page at once).

Does anybody have any experience or advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I used a different method than that described by @IMSoP; I would be interested to hear any views on which is more efficient or considered better practice.

At the end of the queued task, a JSON response is pushed onto a Redis store (the key is the unique user id and the value is the JSON response). In the browser, AJAX is used to run a PHP file every two seconds, with this file checking if the Redis store has a key matching the user id yet. Once found, it returns the value to the browser, then deletes the key=>value pair on Redis.

Comment: nice work explain that, but I find it unnecessary to send every 2 seconds an ajax request, you just hammering your redis store. in my opinion try to make a websocket server persist that with the queue, so when the worker is done doing their job, we can send back a request through that websocket full duplex connection but first thing is we need that user to subscribe to that websocket connection.

1. the user send that request to the backend, the backend raise an event to the queue and also opens a websocket connection.

Answer (score 3):

The RabbitMQ site has [a tutorial on building a request-response "RPC" flow](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-php.html) which sounds like exactly what you're after.

As you say, a single "response" queue won't work, because you can't choose which items you get out of a queue, you get them all in order. Instead, the trick is to create *a separate response queue for each client* (or, for the simplest implementation, a response queue for each request).

You do this by declaring an "anonymous" queue, which isn't really anonymous, it has its name chosen for you by RabbitMQ. You can then send that name as part of your request (conventionally, in the `reply_to` header of the AMQP message) so that the worker on the other end knows where to send the response. In php-amqplib, that looks like this:

```
list($reply_queue_name, ,) = $channel->queue_declare("", false, false, true, false);
```

Note:

- The `queue_declare` call returns an array with the name and status of the queue; we only want the name, so we discard the rest of the array with a `list()` construct.
- The queue name is passed in as the empty string, telling the server to create a name of its choosing.
- The 4th parameter is set to `true` to declare the queue "exclusive"; that means as soon as this connection ends, the queue will be cleaned up.

Comment: Thank you. This seems like a good solution, though I ended up doing it a different way using Redis. I'll post my method as an answer too.

Comment: @IMSoP, I know this method of RPC Is available for RabbitMQ, but my question is this a widely used approach in distributed systems? Are large tech companies, using this approach for e-commerce checkouts? In a sense, while creating orders, is the order payload sent via amqp and then response returned via queue's itself? If yes, wouldn't this just streamline the `HTTP` `REST` APIs?

Comment: Additionally, if there are more then a million customers, then wouldn't this just create a million connections to the queue? I'm curios as to what is the ideal approach? create orders via REST or via AMPQ? Or is the approach followed by OP the correct way to go about it?